# Access once to the child and then reuse the parent in jQuery (1.9.x and more)

Tags: jquery, find, parent

I'm looking a better to do this job, I would like to fill the caption of the image clicked, and I am sure there is a better solution.

Thanks for your answers,
Allan.
(fr)

Jquery is :

```
$bImg
  .find('.title, .caption')
    .fadeIn()
  .parent()
  .find('.title')
    .text(title)
  .parent()
  .find('.caption')
    .text(caption);
```

The HTML is:

```
<div class="big-image carousel">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/450x240/FFFFCC">
   <div class="title">ThIs PhOtO</div>
   <div class="caption">Itaque earum rerum hic in tenetur</div>
</div>
```

PS : `$bImg = $('.big-image');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$bImg
  .find('.title, .caption')
    .fadeIn()
  .filter('.title') // gets .title out of the collection
    .text(title)
  .siblings('.caption')
    .text(caption);
```

Answer (score 1):

A much more efficient way of doing the same would be:

```
$bImg.find('.title').text(title).fadeIn();
$bImg.find('.caption').text(caption).fadeIn();
```

Unless you have an absolute need to do it in one line, the above should be preferred as it finds each element only once and uses the cached object for all subsequent uses - unlike in the original code which gets afresh all items at least 2 times (parent - 3 times, .title - 2 times and .caption - 2 times)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.title, .caption', '.big-image').fadeIn().text(function() { 
    return $(this).is('.title') ? title : caption; 
});
```